# Correlation of state and observation error terms in state space model

Tags: r, time-series, correlation, state-space-models

One of the key assumptions of the state space model is that correlation of state and observation error terms should be zero.
Does this have to be the expected error terms?
How do I test for correlation of error terms of state and observation equations (in R)?